# How to syncronize manually created the sales rates in invoice on quickbook online?

Tags: c#, workflow, quickbooks-online, invoice

[image]
When I syncronize Invoice from Workflow(website) to quickbook online using desktop application. In this case when I sync Invoice all the data gets properly added in Invoice quickbook online. But the sales rate is default selected "based on location". so I want manually created sale rate in invoice.

Here the code for how to sync sales rate from workflow to quickbook online :

```
var queryRate = new QueryService<TaxRate>(context);

      string sqlRate = string.Format("select * from TaxRate where Name = '{0}'", tblInvoice.SaleTaxFullName);  //here tblInvoice.SaleTaxFullName = 'Sales Tax'

      var taxRate = queryRate.ExecuteIdsQuery(sqlRate).FirstOrDefault();

      Line[] lines = new Line[1];
      TaxLineDetail taxLineDetail = new TaxLineDetail()
      {
        TaxRateRef = new ReferenceType()
        {
          Value = taxRate.Id,   // Id = 12
          name = taxRate.Name   //Sales Tax
        },

        NetAmountTaxable = Math.Round((Convert.ToDecimal(tblInvoice.SubTotal)), 2),
        NetAmountTaxableSpecified = true,
        PercentBased = true,
        TaxPercent = taxRate.RateValue,
        TaxPercentSpecified = true,
      };

      lines[0] = new Line()
      {
        Amount = Math.Round((Convert.ToDecimal(tblInvoice.SaleTaxAmount)), 2),
        AmountSpecified = true,
        AnyIntuitObject = taxLineDetail,
        DetailType = LineDetailTypeEnum.TaxLineDetail,
        DetailTypeSpecified = true,
      };

      var queryTax = new QueryService<TaxCode>(context);

      string sqlTax = string.Format("select * from TaxCode where Name = '{0}'", tblInvoice.SaleTaxFullName);

      var tax = queryTax.ExecuteIdsQuery(sqlTax).FirstOrDefault();
      invoice.TxnTaxDetail = new TxnTaxDetail()
      {

        TotalTax = Math.Round((Convert.ToDecimal(tblInvoice.SaleTaxAmount)), 2),
        TotalTaxSpecified = true,
        TaxLine = lines,
        TxnTaxCodeRef = new ReferenceType()
        {

          Value = tax.Id,  
          name = tax.Name

        },
      };
```

Please let me know how can I do that.